# Service method not getting fired using .then

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is my AngularJs code where I am trying to call TalentPoolService.search() after succussfull ProcessCriteria call, however for some reason it not hitting the TalentPool.Service. What am I doing wrong here?

```
       $scope.Search = function (item, SolrLabel) {
    if (item != null) {
        console.log('Item: ' + item.Key);
        console.log('SolrLabel: ' + SolrLabel);
        console.log($localStorage.message);

        var pvarrData = new Array();
        pvarrData[0] = JSON.stringify($localStorage.message);
        pvarrData[1] = item.Key;
        pvarrData[2] = SolrLabel;

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/api/TalentPool/ProcessCriteria',
                data: JSON.stringify(pvarrData),
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            }).then(function (response) {
                console.log('ProcessCriteria Success fired');
                $localStorage.message = response.data;
                console.log(response.data);
                return response.data;
                },
                    function (response) { 
                        // failed
                        console.log('facet post error occured!');
                    }).then(

                          function () {
                              TalentPoolService.search().then(function successCallback(response1) {
                                  $scope.talentpoolist = response1.data.model;
                                  $localStorage.message = response1.data.baseCriteria;
                                  console.log('TalentPoolService.search successCallback fired');
                                  setTimeout(function () {
                                      LetterAvatar.transform();
                                  }, 20);
                              }, function errorCallback(response1) {
                                  $scope.errors = [];
                                  $scope.message = 'Unexpected Error while saving data!!' + response;
                              })
                          }
                    );
    }
}
```

Comment: `TalentPoolService.search()` must be wrapped in a function I think.

Comment: Did tried that but no luck

Comment: Update the question with tried one.

Comment: Have updated the code, please have a look,

Comment: You must return something in the above then to chain the response using then. Then only then works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must return data for chaining to work.

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/api/TalentPool/ProcessCriteria',
  data: JSON.stringify(pvarrData),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log('ProcessCriteria Success fired');
    $localStorage.message = response.data;
    console.log(response.data);
    return response.data; // **return here**
  },
  function(response) {
    // failed
    console.log('facet post error occured!');
  }).then(

  function() {
    TalentPoolService.search().then(function successCallback(response1) {
      $scope.talentpoolist = response1.data.model;
      $localStorage.message = response1.data.baseCriteria;
      setTimeout(function() {
        LetterAvatar.transform();
      }, 20);
    }, function errorCallback(response1) {
      $scope.errors = [];
      $scope.message = 'Unexpected Error while saving data!!' + response;
    })
  }
);
```

Why because, the next then which you are using expects some data to work on. So, if you don't return it can't. So, must return data.

Comment: I can now see 'TalentPoolService.search successCallback fired' message in console however it never hit the the alentPoolService.search() itself.? (Code updated)

Comment: You got success callback. Now, what is the error you are facing.

Comment: Inside TalentPoolService.search() successCallback function I have added a Console message "'TalentPoolService.search successCallback fired'". Now When I run my page, I am able to see the console message however it never hit the server method that should get hit by the TalentPoolService.search Service.

Comment: The error must be in your service. Here `http` call works fine.

Comment: But I am able to call the service from other controller smoothly, not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Just spotted the issue: I was passing response instead of response1 in  TalentPoolService.search().errorCallback

Comment: All the best.. :-)